# Invoking a method/class from another file

Tags: java, eclipse

I think I know how to invoke a method from `ClassA` in `ClassB`(ex. `ClassA cl = ClassA`), but how do I create that `ClassA`? I mean using Eclipse, which method should I pick (see screenshot below):

`public static void main`

`Constractors from superclass`

`Ìnherited abstract methods`

The `main`method will be in `ClassB.java`, `ClassA.java` will only contain a method which will be called in `ClassB`. I am creating two separate `.java` files because the code is two long and want to separate them for better reading.
Thank you guys!
[image]

Comment: What on earth are you asking here? Notice at the top it says "Java Class", why are you specifying a method name? **Name** would be `ClassB`. And then you would *write* your `selectChoice` in `ClassB`. Presumably.

Comment: Learn programming using some simple text editor like Atom or Sublime, compile from console and use IDE only then. Now it distracts you.

Comment: 1. `ClassA cl = ClassA` is wrong, it is not invoking a method, you probably meant `ClassA a = new ClassA()`, which is calling the constructor. 2. Invoking a method `f` would be written as `a.f()`. 3. it does not matter which method stubs Eclipse should create for you, it is just putting in some text into the java file which you can delete/enter yourself.

Comment: Read some Java Tutorial (e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm)

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann thank you. So even if I pick `public static void main(String arg) it doesn't mean that I have two main methods, right?

Comment: @sumu00 You always have exactly one entry point. If there is two classes with a main(), it does not matter because either way you have to choose which class is the main one. In Eclipse, you don't actually have to do much for that, just right click => run on the class you want that is actually your main.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, maybe I put my question wrong, I meant from the 3 options under "Which method stubs.......", which one should I choose if that `.java` file shouldn't contain `main`method. But in any case, you could be nicer, or just skip it

Comment: @kutschkem thank you. Glad that stackoverflow has ppl who just answer question instead of showing their superiority and getting mad.

Comment: You usually check the `public static void main(String arg)` box only once for your main class. Constructors are nice to have, having inherited abstract methods can be very useful, but is useless when you inherit from java.lang.Object

Comment: I agree with @Adder, you do not need method stubs at all. Just leave the the boxes empty.

Comment: Question title and body are quite a bit different, title is asking how to call a method on another class, while body is asking which options to pick in eclipse.  Can you edit one or the other so they match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should brush up your Java basics. For learning Java in an easy way, please go through the book HeadFirst Java. (https://zimslifeintcs.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/head-first-java-2nd-edition.pdf)

Now, to answer your Question:

1. In the image that you have attached, change the "Name" from "selectChoice" to ClassA or ClassB. Name denotes the class name.
2. After clicking on Finish, the class ClassA or ClassB would be automatically generated.

> ```
> public class ClassA{
>    public void methodA(){
>       your implementation here...
>    }
> }
> ```

3. Now create ClassB. If ClassB is in the same package as ClassA, you don't need to import ClassA. Else, you have to import ClassB in the following:

import packageStructure.ClassA;

```
public class ClassB{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       ClassA a = new ClassA();
       a.methodA();
       //other code here
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. `ClassA`and `ClassB`were just examples. I have not decided with the actual class name:), most probably will be SelectChoice. My question was if I needed to tickle one of the check-boxes under Methods in the screenshot even if that 2nd class isn't main class. But I got it answered, so thanks anyways!